# Listview help needed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I am confused being a relatively new user to vb.net. Why my listview is not amending the value in the list? If I may, so I have a correct working of how listview displays its data from database. I have a general question in addition to my code problem.

I have five columns in my listview (0-4). Am I correct in saying that if my access database contained say 10 fields but I only needed to display five of them but one of them was field (9), then would code the list like my code below, which is not changing the value and will only display the list if I remove the 'else' statement.

What is the error? Many thanks

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
oledbCnn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.storageConnectionString
        oledbCnn.Open()

        'drcount = Convert.ToInt32(dr("RowCount"))

        sql = "Select TOP 100 * from Requests ORDER BY [Date-time received] DESC"
        Debug.Print(sql)
        Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, oledbCnn)


        Using dr = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()


            'clear items in the list before populating with new values
            'lvRequests.Items.Clear()

            While dr.Read()
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    Dim LVI As New ListViewItem

                    With LVI
                        .Text = dr(0).ToString()
                        .UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                        .SubItems.Add(CDate(dr(5)).ToShortDateString())
                        .SubItems.Add(dr(1).ToString())
                        .SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())
                        If dr(3).ToString = "D" Then
                            .SubItems(3).Text = "Destroyed"
                        ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "O" Then
                            .SubItems(3).Text = "Out"
                        ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "I" Then
                            .SubItems(3).Text = "Intake"
                        End If
                        .SubItems.Add(dr(9).ToString())
                        If dr(9).ToString = "DEMO" Then
                            .SubItems(9).Text = "Done"

                        End If
                    End With
                    lvRequests.Items.Add(LVI)

                    lvcount += 1

                End If

            End While
        End Using
```

Comment: what matters is how many columns are in your SQL statement and how the data gets into the LV.  Without the SQL (and therefore how many data columns there are to deal with `SELECT *` vs 'Select A, B, C, D, J FROM').  BUT, if you are only posting 5 bits of info to the LV, then you probably should be referencing `SubItems(5)`.  Also it is possible to have hidden SubItems in a LV.  If you add 9 SubItems, but only have 5 Columns defined, then only the first 5 will show.  Too hard to tell more from that little snippet.  However, a DataGridView is often a better choice for grid display of data.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix. So from what you have said, as an example, in mycode above, the field I want is field 9 in access starting at 0, so in my example, dr(9) and subitems(9) are correct?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough info to be really sure what is going on.  It appears that you pull 10 columns from the DB, but if you only post 5 of them to the LV, then there should only be 5 subitems.  So this is wrong:

```
If dr(9).ToString() = "DEMO" Then
    lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems(9).Text = "Done"

' should probably be: 
If dr(9).ToString() = "DEMO" Then
    lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems(4).Text = "Done"
```

What might make it clearer at least in code would be to use Names for the subitems.  If you instance a SubItem object rather than use a default constructor, you can assign a name and reference them that way instead:

```
Dim si As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
With si
    .Text = dr(X).ToString        ' dunno whats in there
    ' this is probably not exactly right, but give the SubItem 
    ' the same name as the db column
    .Name = dr.Table.Columns(X).ColumnName
End With

thisItem.SubItems.Add(si)         ' add sub to Item collection
```

Now, your code can use the name rather than index:

```
If dr(9).ToString() = "DEMO" Then
    lvReq.Items(lvReq.Items.Count - 1).SubItems("TheColumnName").Text = "Done"
```

it no longer really matters how many columns or subitems there are.  The ListViewItem.SubItems collection does not require sub item names to be unique, so it is possible to end up with 2 with the same name, but if you map from the DR/DT/DB correctly, it should take care of itself.

If the LV is **bound** to the datasource (you did not say), then there could be as many SubItems as db/datasource columns (never actually used an LV that way).

Comment: I am still not 100% clear on the answer. It is unbound btw. So I am clear in my own head. In my updated code, column 4 is fetching it's data from field 9 in access. My code displays the correct data in column 4 but does not amend the text but the previous code dr(3) amends correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the extra code - you add 4 subitems with the last one being from `dr(9)` which looks like a status.  But the last bit of code, after adding the **fourth** subItem, you try to put "Done" into the **ninth** subitem.  Try this: `.SubItems(LVI.SubItems.Count-1).Text = "Done"`

Comment: Still the same Plutonix. Why the hell is this so difficult.

Comment: actually, Count-1 would be wrong. `SubItem(0).Text` is the same as `Item.Text` so you can loop thru SubItems to get all the text for an item.  So even though it is 0 based, sub item 4 would be index 4: `.SubItems(4).Text = "Done"`.  The fact that it does not throw an error with `SubItems(9).Text = "Done"` means elsewhere you HAVE added a ninth col/subItem.  It may not show if there are fewer columns than subitems (neat way to hide data from users).  Consider named columns though for less confusion

Comment: I think it has to do with a NULL entry. In debug it shows as: System.IsDBNull. Thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what `it` refers to but sounds like it traces back to the DB.  Try using an ELSE `If db(9).ToString = "DEMO" Then .SubItems.Add("DONE") ELSE .SubItems.Add("Not DONE") End If` that will keep a Null out of the LV at any rate.

Comment: Now I am confused. I have slightly modified the code and for the life of me don't understand why this works when the text value is 'DEMO'. If IsDBNull(dr(9)) Then
                                .SubItems(LVI.SubItems.Count - 1).Text = "No Status"

                            ElseIf dr(9) IsNot "DEMO" Then
                                .SubItems(LVI.SubItems.Count - 1).Text = "Done"

                            End If. Any thoughts?